# JPA/HIBERNATE: How to pass value in @where clause

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, persistence

I would like to know if it is possible to configure dynamic @where clauses with JPA anotations. Let's say I have a relationship between two classes - company (parent) and invoces (child).

If have a Annotation declaration like this (pseudo code).

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_MEN_PRE", referencedColumnName = "ID_MEN"
@Where(clause="invoice_month=:month")
private Testinvoices invoice;
```

What I would like to do now is to pass "month" value in the where clause. The result should return only Testinvoices by the given Date.

Is there a way how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, however Filters - see further below - can be parameterized.

However it looks to me like you are attempting to model a relationship when actually a query would be a better solution.

Or, create a view filtered by date at the database Level and map invoices to that view rather than a table.

17.1. Hibernate filters

> Hibernate3 has the ability to pre-define filter criteria and attach
>   those filters at both a class level and a collection level. A filter
>   criteria allows you to define a restriction clause similar to the
>   existing "where" attribute available on the class and various
>   collection elements. **These filter conditions, however, can be
>   parameterized.** The application can then decide at runtime whether
>   certain filters should be enabled and what their parameter values
>   should be. Filters can be used like database views, but they are
>   parameterized inside the application.

Answer (score 1):

```
This is not possible in JPA.

For same effect you can use criteria. Please refer to example below

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employees.class);

if (subsidiaryId != null) {
  criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("subsidiaryId", subsidiaryId));
}
if (employeeId != null) {
  criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("employeeId", employeeId));
}
if (lastName != null) {
  criteria.add(
    Restrictions.eq("lastName", lastName).ignoreCase()
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to passe a parameter during the runtime but it is possible to use it like this way

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_MEN_PRE", referencedColumnName = "ID_MEN"
@Where(clause="invoice_month=january")
private Testinvoices invoice;
```